# comma separated argument for IN operator, MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, find-in-set

I have a table in which the following query works fine:

```
select * 
from session_actions 
where action_type IN ('login_failed','channel_recorded')
```

Now I'm looking forward to some thing like the following:

```
select * 
from session_actions 
where action_type IN ('login_failed,channel_recorded')
```

As you see I want to give the `IN` operator one single comma separated parameter, but it is not possible

How can I convert this comma separated string into a list of parameters which is acceptable to `IN` operator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be looking for **[FIND_IN_SET()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php)** function.

```
select * 
from session_actions 
where find_in_set(`action_type`,'login_failed,channel_recorded');
```

**[SAMPLE FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2b8a/2)**

Answer (score 0):

I tried `FIND_IN_SET` but it was super slow. I rather use `haystack REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]', needle, '[[:>:]]')` since then.