# SQL NOT IN with comparison list from SELECT

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I've 2 tables.

First with Id and Name: like TAB_FIRST.first_id as INT and TAB_FIRST.first_name as VARCHAR.

The second table as unique ID, name and (that's the key...) a VARCHAR field with a list of Id from the first table. So this field contain data like "26,27,29,28,25,35"

I want to get data from the first table, which Ids are not in the list of If of the second one.

If I perform:

```
SELECT
first_id,
first_name
FROM TAB_FIRST
WHERE first_id NOT IN (26,27,29,28,25,35)
```

I works. If I use  NOT IN ('26','27','29','28','25','35') it works too.

But when I remplace the hard coded list by a select, the NOT IN don't filter the data and I get all data from first table.
So:

```
SELECT
first_id,
first_name
FROM TAB_FIRST
WHERE first_id NOT IN (SELECT second_list_id FROM TAB_SECOND)
```

doesn't work.

I'm pretty sure this came from the fact I try to perform the NOT IN between an INT (first_id) and a list which is a "string". I tried to CAT/CONVERT first_id, try to perform a LOCATE on the list adding '' and so on. Each time same result.
Is there a way to do that (without using a third table to link id from first table with id from second one).

Thanks a lot

Comment: You should fix your data model and stop storing CSV in the `second_list_id` column.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I perfectly know it would be the best way. The problem is that the design has been made this way. So is there an other option, so performing a NOT IN between an INT and a list? That's the question.

Comment: As reply made by Shadow, this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171832/comma-separated-argument-for-in-operator-mysql give the answer, using find in set.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `second_list_id` is not the SQL array that it would expect within `NOT IN`, it's just a string with comma-separated IDs in it, as you said. You would need to parse/split this into a proper array for the `NOT IN` matching to work as expected. How you do this depends on what dialect of SQL you're using:

- MySQL doesn't have a built-in way to do this, but you can check out https://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/ for an example of creating your own function to accomplish it.
- MS SQL Server does have a [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) method that can be used for this purpose.

Another option would be to just perform 2 queries; the first to pull out `second_list_id`, then parse that in code, and another to query with your `NOT IN` using that parsed list of IDs.

Comment: To exclude identifiers which are stored in another table you have to use `LEFT JOIN`.